# Who voted and viewed my profile

Tags: support

Like most of us have LinkedIn profile. I am sure you must have received mails like  10 users viewed your profile.

Generates curiosity, who viewed? And when you check, they will show limited profiles and for rest one has to pay.

Is it possible to see WHO viewed my profile on UX.SE?
And WHO voted for my answer?

Comment: And I, for one, hate that feature on linked in. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stack Exchange isn't a social network, it's a Q&A site. There is no value to knowing that `user53168` visited your profile as you cannot contact them or do anything of value with that information.

Also, voting is anonymous, so there is no way to know who has voted. Again, there is no benefit to knowing this, there are only negatives ("oh, `user76436` voted for my answer so I better vote for something of theirs too incase they think I don't like them"...)

The site focuses on, and revolves around Questions and Answers, not individual users activity, so yeah, let's leave LinkedIn to do what they're good at and stick with what works well here.